# How to target child of a div below in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code

```
<div class="header"> 
  <div class="one_cont">Div one!</div>  
</div>

<div class="project" id="trigger1">
  <div class="text" id="anim1">Div two!</div>
</div>

<div class="project" id="trigger2">
  <div class="text" id="anim2">Div two!</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the each loop on each one of the divs but I am not sure how to target the inner div of each project

```
// Init ScrollMagic
$(document).ready(function() {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    // Create a Scene
    $(".project").each(function() {
        var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: this,
            triggerHook: 0.25
        })
        .setClassToggle($(this).next(), "fade-in")
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
    });
});
```

I tried using

```
.setClassToggle( $(this).next(),
```

but this doesn't seem to work. What would be a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) or [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as the element `div` is a child, the method `.next()` targets immediately following sibling thus its not working.

```
.setClassToggle( $(this).children("div"), "fade-in")
```

As per [Docs](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#setClassToggle)

> A Selector targeting one or more elements or a DOM object that is supposed to be modified.

its accepts a DOM element or selector, You need to pass DOM element thus use

```
.setClassToggle( $(this).children("div")[0], "fade-in")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `children()` instead of `next()` to target inner div

```
.setClassToggle( $(this).children("div"), "fade-in")
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get "ERROR calling method 'setClassToggle()': Invalid element supplied."